# How to get $http response and assign to local variable using services?

Tags: angularjs

service.js

```
     angular.module('app')
        .service('tableService', [
        '$q',
      tableService
  ]);

  function tableService($q){
    var tableData = [
      {
        issue: 'Vinayak N',
        progress: 100,
       // status: 69,
        class: 'md-accent'
      }
    ];
}
```

i want to make a call to $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/studentsList'); and assign the response.data to a local variable tableData in service.js

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
angular.module('app')
        .service('tableService', [
        '$q','$http',
      tableService
  ]);

  function tableService($q, $http){
    var tableData = [
      {
        issue: 'Vinayak N',
        progress: 100,
       // status: 69,
        class: 'md-accent'
      }
    ];
    $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/studentsList').then(function(result){
      tableData.data = result.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: javascript is async you cannot do this.

Comment: @Inayath So, I think problem is with the table. It's rendered before the data is loaded, right?

Answer (score 0):

**You must bind your variable in your service to your controller.**

> $http.get('http://localhost:500/api/studentList').then(function(res){
>   tableService.tableData = res; });

There are lot of ways to bind them. It's really up to you on how you will manipulate your codes.

Answer (score 0):

First Create a service

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('tableService', tableService);
function tableService($q, $http, $cookies) {
  return {
    tableData: tableData
  };

  function tableData() {
    var d = $q.defer();
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/studentsList'
    }).success(function(response) {
      d.resolve(response);
    }).error(function(response) {
      d.reject(response);
    });
    return d.promise;
  }
}
```

Note: I created factory, you can do that through service also

Create your controller and call service inside controller

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('tableController', tableController);
function tableController($scope, tableService) {
  $scope.tableData = [];
  tableData();

function tableData() {
    tableService.tableData().then(function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
          $scope.tableData = response.data;
        }
    }, function() {
    });
   }
}
```